# Date field always in previous day in Java

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis

I am facing an issue with dates in Java.

My stack is spring boot and MyBatis. My service (REST API) returns back

```json
{
    "currency": "USD",
    "totalAmount": 120000,
    "dueDate": "2023-05-22T23:00:00.000+0000",
    "financedAmount": 0,
    "unfinancedAmount": 120000
}
```

I would expect back 2023-05-23T.... The date is always **one day** before at 23:00.

This is the date command at the system that runs the spring boot service.

```bash
admin@ip-10-24-232-126:~$ date
Mon Mar 27 20:05:13 BST 2023
```

Oracle that runs on another machine, gives these results

1. `SELECT systimestamp FROM dual` -> **2023-03-27 19:51:24.465096 +01:00**
2. `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual;` -> **+00:00**

My java entity defines the dueDate fiels as:

```java
private final Date dueDate;
```

and when I run the sql query from oracle (no java, just straight the select on sql developer) I got:
2023-05-23 (at the due date column). My setup is java and mybatis, the mybatis framework transforms the dueDate with the following (XML) mapping.

```xml
<result column="D_DUE_DT" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" property="dueDate" />
```

My problem is that instead of receiving 2023-05-23T..., I receive 2023-05-22T.. How can I resolve this? I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Have you checked if it is a timezone issue?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I check this?

Comment: Are you expecting that `05-23` is at `00:00` (midnight)? If so, then your result is just one hour behind (not necessarily a day). Note the difference between `systimestamp` and `DBTIMEZONE` is a 1-hour timezone offset: that `+01:00` is UTC+1. Your `date` command also noted that the system timezone is `BST` (aka `UTC+1`), so you're seeing the difference between your system's time and (potentially) your client's time. More information about how this date is created and read would be helpful.

Comment: @Rogue So is the problem related with the system configuration? what should we change?

Comment: You have for sure a timezone issue, Timezone BST is UTC+1, as `2023-05-22T23:00:00.000+0000` == `2023-05-23T00:00:00.000+0100`.
Where do you receive the date in your endpoint from and how do you pass it on to the answer of your REST endpoint?

Comment: A problem you have for sure is that `java.util.Date` and so also `java.sql.Date` do not store a timezone, so it depends on the way how you put the data into there if the systems timezone setting is relevant. Please also specify the Java version you are using.

Comment: @cyberbrain The data are transformed to "java" from mybatis. I use Jackson to send the date back to the client.

Comment: @cyberbrain java 8

Comment: I have no experience with MyBatis, so I would try to use `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date` - or if that doesn't work, `java.time.OffsetDateTime` or `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.  But `TIMESTAMP` usually doesn't store timezone information, so the problem comes from some conversion in Java.

Comment: @GrafanaNext What is the exact type of the `D_DUE_DT` column? I think it only happens when the data type is `timestamp with local time zone`.

Comment: Why do you say "The date is always one day before at 23:00"? This makes no sense.

Comment: FYI, both of the `Date` classes bundled with Java are terribly flawed. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Your whole question is confusing. Edit to state simply what code you ran, what result you got, and what result you expected. This bouncing around from JSON, to SQL, to XML is distracting, and seemingly unhelpful. At no point do you actually discuss the Java code that gave you an unexpected value in your JSON - so you neglected to document the very core of your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date returned from the REST API is in GMT (with the +0000 offset), which is causing the date to appear one day earlier at 23:00 instead of I guess 00:00 of the day you want. Your system is set to BST (= GMT+1), same for your DB.

You need to make sure that all components of your application are using the same time zone.